# How to align these tables in different Divs

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

Consider the following snap on my site.

[image]

The area in red is a table that's being rendered dynamically and is in a separate div. The bottom 3 rows are in a different tables in a different div which is static. As these two are basically different tables, the check boxes don't align themselves. These divs are part of a liquid layout and are in the left hand column. Is there a way to align them without fixing the table, row and column widths? Or maybe fool those two tables to believe that they are actually one and align them?

Here is the structure

```
<div id='dynamic_in_red_border'>
    <table id="one">
    </table>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <table id="static">
    </table>
</div>
```

Hope my question is clear.

PS: the red box is just to make my point, its not there on the actual UI

Comment: You can dynamically insert the table into the div (vice versa would be better), which would make it easy. But tables and divs don't play well...

Comment: even if i do that they would still be two different tables and wont align right? the table on the top is already being inserted dynamically.

Comment: I had a few tables which did align fine with each other (even though they were separated by content).

Comment: these are two separate tables. I just put the structure in the question to make it clearer

Comment: How are they created (serverside or clientside)?

Comment: Client Side. The div on top us being rendered using javascript in a ruby on rails app. so for the first time basically its a partial included.

Comment: If the border was not necessary, you could just dynamically insert rows...

Comment: Wait, I am sorry i did not mention that. Border is just an illustration, to make my point. its not actually there on the UI. So you mean after the first table is render I should dynamically insert the other 3 rows using javascript?

Comment: Why not? Are you using a framework?

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails. OKay i suppose that will work. May be i was just hoping there was some other way to make this work without going into inserting them dynamically. Thanks for the pointer though!

Comment: Not familiar with RoR. You can do jQuery with it, right?

Comment: Yes i can. Infact i am already using it. Thanks for quick help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically insert rows using jQuery or pure JS. I'll do jQuery for now:

**HTML**:

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery)**:

```
var td = $('<td>').html('bar');
var tr = $('<tr>').append(td);

$('table#foo').append(tr);
```

Comment: oops, I have an Problem with this approach. Which i now realize is the reason I did not go this way. The state of the check boxes matter to me when different contents are rendered. So if i render the lower table using the above approach i will have to do quite a bit of juggling to save the state of the check boxes and accordingly render the lower rows. I am still looking for a solution which can align them using plain html or css.

Comment: Remove the tables from the divs and just render them. See what happens,

Comment: but i need atleast one div. to render the top table dynamically. I tried removing the lower div. its still the same..

Comment: I used part of the CSS/HTML of [this site](http://diveintohtml5.org/) in my layout (the Table of Contents specifically). The ToC isn't a table, which is why it works so well for me.

Comment: ah looks great! So a solution for me could be to not use table at all and try to get the alignments right without tables? i have three elements in each row, the legend image, the link and the check box. How you do you align three things without using table? sorry I am no expert in css designs.

Comment: Are they all evenly spaced, or is the image and the link grouped together and on the left, while the checkbox is on the right? You only use tables if your design absolutely needs more than two distinct columns.

Comment: Here, look at this example to see what I mean. No tables: http://jsfiddle.net/peezq/11/.

Comment: Thats an very useful link! thanks for showing that. Yes i i can do away with tables. Thats exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this should work:

```
<style>
div.container {display:table;} /* For a container including both tables */
table {display:table-row-group;}

/* Redundant, but just putting here for experimenting */
tbody {display:table-row-group;}
tr {display:table-row;}
td {display:table-cell;}

/* Add some visible borders */
div, td {border: inset black 2px;}
</style>
```

...but from my tests in Chrome and Firefox, it only works when the file is true XHTML (with XHTML extension or explicit application/xhtml+xml content-type header) or pure XML (.xml extension), and only if there is a single container div.

Comment: thanks for an answer. I am not an expert in css and am looking at what you suggested for the first time. Can you explain a bit that it means and how is it suppose to work for me? or may be point me to some good reference that will explain this. (i am already googling for this syntax you suggested).

Comment: This is probably not the direction for you to go in (due to probable browser support problems), but theoretically these CSS properties should allow you to mimic (and given the possibility for other display elements, one would think also be able to override) the default display behaviors of table elements. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display . E.g., the default display of a div is block and a span as inline, but you can change it to inline and block, respectively if you wished.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but this is what I would try.

You could try wrapping both table container divs in a div (#tables_container), that has position:relative, then give both current divs width 100%. So something in the lines of

```
#tables_container {position:relative; width: 20%; } 
/* width to be the left column width*/
#dynamic_in_red_border table, 
#bottom table {width: 100%;}

<div id="tables_container">
  <div id='dynamic_in_red_border'>
    <table id="one">
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <table id="static">
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

After getting the table-widths to match, you could just give the check-box cells text-align: right. But if you want to align the table cells too, it gets more difficult.